# oracle.jrad.tools.xml.importer.XMLImporter WITH ORA-01704: string literal too long

Tags: java, oracle, oaf

I'm currently trying to import a region, using the `oracle.jrad.tools.xml.importer.XMLImporter` command.

But I get:

> ORA-01704: string literal too long

```
Copyright (c) 2002 Oracle Corporation
                        Redwood Shores, California, USA
                                    AD Java
                                 Version 11.5.0
NOTE: You may not use this utility for custom development
      unless you have written permission from Oracle Corporation.
Reading product information from file...
Reading language and territory information from file...
Reading language information from applUS.txt ...
  Temporarily resetting CLASSPATH to:
  "/u001/oracle/env04appl/ad/11.5.0/java/adjri.zip:/u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/jre/lib/rt.jar:/u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/lib/dt.jar:/u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/lib/tools.jar:/u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/u001/oracle/env04comn/java/appsborg2.zip:/u002/oracle/env04ora/8.0.6/forms60/java:/u001/oracle/env04comn/java"
  Calling /u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/bin/java ... 
Importing /gir/oracle/apps/xxrh/selfservice/sq/rh23286/maj/webui/EnteteArmeElectImpulRefRN14
Error:     

ORA-01704: string literal too long
Import completed.
AD Run Java Command is complete.
```

it worked for my other regions, but this one it doesn't

```
jdr_utils.printDocument(p_document => '/gir/oracle/apps/xxrh/selfservice/sq/rh23286/maj/webui/EnteteArmeElectImpulRefRN14');
```

returns

> **Error: Could not find document /gir/oracle/apps/xxrh/selfservice/sq/rh23286/maj/webui/EnteteArmeElectImpulRefRN14**

what could cause this?

**UPDATE**
If I run it with the -displayOnly flag, I don't get the error

```
                     Copyright (c) 2002 Oracle Corporation
                        Redwood Shores, California, USA

                                    AD Java

                                 Version 11.5.0

NOTE: You may not use this utility for custom development
      unless you have written permission from Oracle Corporation.

Reading product information from file...

Reading language and territory information from file...

Reading language information from applUS.txt ...
  Temporarily resetting CLASSPATH to:
  "/u001/oracle/env04appl/ad/11.5.0/java/adjri.zip:/u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/jre/lib/rt.jar:/u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/lib/dt.jar:/u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/lib/tools.jar:/u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/u001/oracle/env04comn/java/appsborg2.zip:/u002/oracle/env04ora/8.0.6/forms60/java:/u001/oracle/env04comn/java"

  Calling /u002/jdk/jdk1.6.0_121/bin/java ...
Validating /gir/oracle/apps/xxrh/selfservice/sq/rh23286/maj/webui/EnteteArmeElectImpulRefRN14

Documents and Package Files that will be imported:
  /gir/oracle/apps/xxrh/selfservice/sq/rh23286/maj/webui/EnteteArmeElectImpulRefRN14

AD Run Java Command is complete.
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Paul T. , this was my first post

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, 
I had a rawText item with 7160 characters in it. Removing it solved my problem.